# In Java, how to pass the objects back to Main thread from worker threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, how to pass the objects back to Main thread from worker threads? Take the following codes as an example:

```
  main(String[] args) {

    String[] inputs;
    Result[] results;
    Thread[] workers = new WorkerThread[numThreads];

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        workers[i] = new WorkerThread(i, inputs[i], results[i]);
        workers[i].start();
    } 

    ....
  }
  ....

class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    String input;
    int name;
    Result result;

    WorkerThread(int name, String input, Result result) {
        super(name+"");
        this.name = name;
        this.input = input;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void run() {
        result  = Processor.process(input);
    }
}
```

How to pass the `result` back to `main`'s `results[i]` ?

How about passing `this` to `WorkerThread`,

```
workers[i] = new WorkerThread(i, inputs[i], results[i], this);
```

so that it could

```
mainThread.reults[i] = Processor.process(inputs[i]);
```

Comment: You should really just use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads).invokeAll(...)`

Comment: @veer Why? I only run at most 10 threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Callable`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)?

```
main(String[] args) {

  String[] inputs;
  Future<Result>[] results;

  for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    results[i] = executor.submit(new Worker(inputs[i]);
  } 
  for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    Result r = results[i].get();
    // do something with the result
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you on using the Callable, Future, and ExecutorService classes; and a decent example for how to, is provided here: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6

Answer (score 1):

@Thilo's and @Erickson's answers are the best one.  There are existing APIs that do this kind of thing simply and reliably.

But if you want to persist with your current approach of doing it by hand, then the following change to you code may be sufficient:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    results[i] = new Result();
    ...
    workers[i] = new WorkerThread(i, inputs[i], results[i]);
    workers[i].start();
}

...

public void run() {
    Result tmp = Processor.process(input);
    this.result.updateFrom(tmp);
    // ... where the updateFrom method copies the state of tmp into
    // the Result object that was passed from the main thread.
}
```

Another approach is to replace `Result[]` in the main program with `Result[][]` and pass a `Result[0]` to the child thread that can be updated with the result object.  (A light-weight holder).

However, there us an **Important Gotcha** when you are implementing this at a low level is that the main thread needs to call Thread.join on all of the child threads before attempting to retrieve the results.  If you don't, there is a risk that the main thread will *occasionally* see stale values in the Result objects.  The `join` also ensures that the `main` thread doesn't try to access a Result before the corresponding child thread has completed it.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the point that main thread needs to call join( ) on every worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread will need to wait for the worker threads to complete before getting the results.  One way to do this is for the main thread to wait for each worker thread to terminate before attempting to read the result.  A thread terminates when its run() method completes.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
  worker.join(); // wait for worker thread to terminate
  Result result = results[i]; // get the worker thread's result
  // process the result here...
}
```

You still have to arrange for the worker thread's result to be inserted into the result[] array somehow.  As one possibility, you could do this by passing the array and an index into each worker thread and having the worker thread assign the result before terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Some typical solutions would be:

- Hold the result in the worker thread's instance (be it `Runnable` or `Thread`). This is similar to the use of the `Future` interface.
- Use a `BlockingQueue` that the worker threads are constructed with which they can place their result into.
- Simple use the `ExecutorService` and `Callable` interfaces to get a `Future` which can be asked for the result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your goal is to perform the computation in parallel, then once all results are available to the main thread, it can continue and use them.

If that's the case, implement your parallel computation as a [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) rather than a thread. Pass this collection of tasks to the [`invokeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method of an `ExecutorService`. This method will block until all the tasks have been completed, and then your main thread can continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better solution, why don't you make your worker threads pass the result into a linkedListBlockingQueue, which is passed to them, after they are done, and your main function picks the results up from the queue like this

```
while(true){linkedListBlockingQueue.take(); 
    //todo: fil in the task you want it to do
    //if a specific kind of object is returned/countdownlatch is finished exit
}
```