# I have a function, and in it i am running an thread using Anonymous class, so how to return value to that function

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jsoup

The code below will make it more clear:

```
public static String TCMResponse(String params, final Context c) {
    final String url = "https://115.248.161.106/ois/API/android/" + params;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String response="";

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).validateTLSCertificates(false).timeout(6000).get();
                response = doc.text();

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Err","External OIS not reachable!");
            }

            // I want to return 'response' here, for the TCMResponse()
        }
    }).start();
}
```

So as you can see from the code, there is a function, TCMResponse() which takes the parameters of the url which i pass, and it does web scraping, i know all these can be done using volley/ JSONParser easily. But i am just experimenting, how to parse using web scraping.

So after the page is scraped, i need that function to return the response of the scraped page,

I've used Callable with executor service, but it again freezes the thread..
Have a look on what i've done:

```
public static String TCMResponse(String params, final Activity act) {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    final String url = "https://115.248.161.106/ois/API/android/" + params;
    response="";

    class MyBgThread implements Callable<String>
    {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            try{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).validateTLSCertificates(false).timeout(6000).get();
                return doc.text();
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
                Snackbar.with(act, null)
                        .type(Type.ERROR)
                        .message("Something got wrong!")
                        .duration(Duration.LONG)
                        .show();
                return "{'auth':'false'}";
            }
        }
    }

    Callable<String> worker = new MyBgThread();
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<String> future = ex.submit(worker);
    try{
        response = future.get();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Thread Ex",e+"");
    }
    ex.shutdown();
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223882/in-java-how-to-pass-the-objects-back-to-main-thread-from-worker-threads

Comment: This is a well known problem.  You might want to do some research here first, then post a question if you really get stuck.

Comment: The function runs in android, and its async, so any work on thread, makes the UI freeze, and i am unable to understand the possible duplicate which you have provided, sorry.

Comment: I'm building an Android app right now, and I don't have this problem.  Just make your async task class an inner class within the activity which uses it.  It should still be able to access final variables in the containing activity class.

Comment: Yes that will work fine, if done in the same activity. What i am doing is, making the function TCMResponse() static in MainActivity, such that i can access it in another activities. Meanwhile, if i set the repsonse as a global or final vairable, no doubt it gets the value, but only after second call. When for the first time, it returns null, coz at that time the thread is running.

Comment: I have even tried Asynctask().execute().get(); It also freezes the UI

Comment: Could you refactor out the code which the thread executes, and then use an inner class inside the activity?

Comment: I am sorry, not able to get you.

Comment: Threads don't return values.  That's against the entire idea of using a thread-  that it happens asynchronously.  Anything that needs the result of a thread needs to use a listener pattern.

Comment: A `Callable` is always an option.

Comment: Please all the people who replied, have edited the question, please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thread gets blocked because of your call to `Future::get()`.

From the docs:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

which means; if the task `Thread` has not yet finished, the current `Thread` will wait until it returns a result.

---

I can see another problem in your code: you are showing a `Snackbar`, which is a UI component, in a `Thread` that is not the `UI Thread`.

Since you are working on `Android`, I would definitely use an `AsyncTask`, perform the expensive call in `doInBackground()`, then update the UI in `onPostExecute()`.